# Attaching IAM role to AWS RDS instance with Ansible

Tags: ansible, amazon-rds

I created an AWS RDS instance with `oracle-ee` using Ansible (v2.9) `rds_instance` module. Later I realized that I need some DB files on it. So I created an S3 bucket and uploaded some `.dmp` files to it.

I wrote an Ansible task as below to "integrate" the RDS with S3:

```
- name: Update RDS instance with Role ARN for S3 ingestion
  rds_instance:
    region: "{{ region }}"
    aws_access_key: "{{ aws_access_key_id }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_secret_access_key }}"
    db_instance_identifier: my-db-instance
    s3_ingestion_role_arn: "{{ aws_rds_iam_role_arn }}"
    s3_bucket_name: "{{ aws_rds_s3_bucket }}"
    s3_prefix: db
    option_group_name: "{{ aws_rds_option_group }}"
```

**Note**: All variables have been supplied during the Playbook run with `vars_files:`.

Once the task executes, it shows `ok: [localhost]` instead of updating the IAM role on RDS instance.

A quick check on `AssociatedRoles` with AWS CLI shows `null`:

```
$ aws rds describe-db-instances --db-instance-identifier my-db-instance --query "DBInstances[0].AssociatedRoles[0]"
null
```

As per the Ansible documentation for `rds_instance`, I was expecting the specified role to be attached to the RDS instance (at least show up in AWS CLI output above), and the files matching `s3_prefix` available. Am I missing something?

**Note**: I am able to attach the IAM role using AWS CLI and import. However I would like to have this working with Ansible for future RDS instances that we will create.

**Edit**:

Apart from the role being attached to the RDS instance, I was also expecting files matching `s3_prefix` to be copied over from S3 bucket to RDS instance.
I've looked into the `DATA_DUMP_DIR` but there is only `datapump/` directory inside (no `*.dmp` files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately I had to resort to a slightly long-ish *workaround* using AWS CLI commands and SQL scripts to download the dump (`*.dmp`) files from the S3 bucket.

**Attach the IAM role with S3_INTEGRATION option to RDS instance:**

```yaml
- name: Attach IAM role to RDS instance
  command: "aws rds add-role-to-db-instance --instance-identifier my-db-instance --feature-name S3_INTEGRATION --role-arn {{ aws_rds_iam_role_arn }}"
  register: attach_result
  failed_when:
  - attach_result.rc > 0
  - "'already associated' not in attach_result.stderr"
```

This made sure that the IAM Role that authorizes access to S3 is attached to my RDS instance.

Next step is to import. But before that, I verify the role is present and active.

```yaml
- name: Verify IAM role with S3_INTEGRATION is present
  command: aws cli describe-db-instances --instance-identifier my-db-instance --query DBInstances[0].AssociatedRole[0].FeatureName --output json
  register: verify_iam_role
- name: Fail if S3_INTEGRATION is not present
  fail:
    msg: "S3_INTEGRATION is not available."
  when: "'S3_INTEGRATION' not in verify_iam_role.stdout"
```

**Create SQL script (using template) to import:**

Ansible task:

```yaml
- name: Create SQL script to copy from S3
  template:
    src: copy-from-s3.sql.j2
    dest: /tmp/copy-from-s3.sql
```

SQL script:

```sql
SELECT rdsadmin.rdsadmin_s3_tasks.download_from_s3(p_bucket_name => 'my-s3-bucket', p_s3_prefix => 'db_', p_directory_name => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR') AS TASK_ID FROM DUAL;
```

**Finally run the SQL script:**

```yaml
- name: Run SQL script
  command: "sqlplus dbuser/dbpasswd@my-db-instance-endpoint:1521 @/tmp/copy-from-s3.sql"
```

This generates a log file with a Task ID. Completion status is updated in the file. Now `db_*.dmp` files are available.

Answer (score 1):

s3_ingestion_role_arn is the role used to access the s3 bucket to import the s3 dumps, but its not permanent role, so once the operation completes, the role job is finished.

Comment: If that is the case, where would I find the dumps (`*.dmp`) in the RDS instance? I have looked in `DATA_DUMP_DIR` but could not find any files copied over. I will edit the original question too.

Comment: do you mean automatic snapshots

Comment: No. We have some `db*.dmp` files in an S3 bucket which we would like to use for the RDS instance. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I submitted a feature request to implement this directly in rds_instance module, https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.aws/issues/464

Comment: Very nice! It seems appropriate that this functionality is handled by the module itself.